# Understanding custom scope in spring

Tags: spring, scope

I need help in understanding the custom scope in spring I went through the reference manual and do have some understanding about it but the question which is bugging me is **when actually the call to the get method of my implementation of scope interface is made** Though my understanding is  if a bean with scope=myscope is defined then Spring calls the get method on my scope implementation to retrieve the object . But when I came across an example I noticed something strange.

The call to get method is not made at the execution of following statement

```
Object targetBean = getApplicationContext().getBean(task.getBeanName());
```

**but on the execution of following statement**.

```
ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(targetMethod, targetBean, arguments);
```

Can any one help me by explaining more about custom scope implementation and call of get method.

PS : In the concerned example the Custom scope is used with Threadlocal .. If any one can provide me a working example link of customscope with thread local ,it will be a great help

Answer (score 3):

I have made extensive use of custom scopes in the past to inject stateful objects into singleton services.

My understanding is that a proxy wraps the bean that is custom scoped and the proxy retrieves the bean from the scope on the method invocation of the bean.

See also [Spring Indepth](http://www.springindepth.com/book/in-depth-ioc-scope.html)

So in your case

```
Object targetBean = getApplicationContext().getBean(task.getBeanName());
```

`targetBean` will be the proxy

```
ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(targetMethod, targetBean, arguments);
```

Invokes the method on the proxy which calls through `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.Scope#get` to retrieve the correct bean

Comment: Just an FYI, the link for the Spring Indepth article or book is dead.  I'm not sure how much it matters 7 years later.